# In Death Race 2 who was killed in the shower?

Tags: death-race-2

In the closing moments of the film Lists is in the shower and watches someone being killed, presumably this is part of Carl Lucas' revenge (as it's shown in parallel with the other payback killings).

Who is murdered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1500491/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl),

> [Luke] joins the race as the new character "Frankenstein" with a mask to hide his identity from others, especially September, who is threatening not only his life but Katrina's as well. Meanwhile, Luke's new Triad friends manage to kill Marcus in revenge, and **List kills Rocco in the shower house for rigging Luke's car**. Frankenstein then kills September by running her over with his car during a race, leaving some fates (such as Katrina's) unresolved.